# What is the quickest and most simple way of **integer factorization by hand**?

Tags: prime-factorization

I've searched for some algorithms but still wonder which method is best for human to calculate a not that big one such as:
Calculate the factorization of 2345 and 3456

Note: Just for the examples, you will see it's not random number. Is there special method for such number?

Comment: Keep dividing by two until no factors of two left. Keep dividing by three until no factors of three left. Repeat for primes five, seven, 11, 13... until you reach one.

Comment: There are well-known tricks for testing divisibility by $2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,15,16,\ldots$, and some less well known for testing divisibility by $7,13,17,37$ etc.

Comment: @David Not that $4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, \ldots$ are really necessary to check, seing as they're not primes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In special cases (like these ones) you can use the difference of two squares.

3456 = 3600 - 144 = $60^2 - 12^2$ = (60 + 12)(60-12) = 72 * 48

2345 = 2601 - 256 = $51^2 - 16^2$ = (51 + 16)(51-16) = 67 * 35

From there it is straightforward to factor.

Comment: Yes I did. That's what I get for rereading the question while typing.